# Should we accept edits that add resources to a list?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Take a look at [suggested edit #1571514](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1571514). It's to a post that lists some regex testers with a question if we could ["contribute some more to [the] collection?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003802/online-regex-tester) This question isn't about the question - it obviously should have been closed. I'm asking about adding another resource to a bulleted list of resources - should we reject or accept the edit?

This isn't an inquiry just about question edits, but also answers. Take a question that's asks for some ARM assembly manuals. The highest rated answer would likely be just a list of resources. What would we do there?

Comment: I'd say that depends on the nature of the situation - whether it's a question or an answer, for example. In that specific case, the entire question was ripe for closing and deletion, so I guess the question is moot; in general, bullet point lists with resources inside the question are a telltale sign of trouble

Comment: accept if they're viable entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was a tag wiki, and you're sure the resource is valid, *and* it enhances the wiki entry, then I would say "Sure, approve it".

In this case, the original user didn't find the resource, someone else just added it.  We don't know the editor's intentions (are they trying to promote a tool of theirs?), and it really doesn't enhance the question, so it should have been rejected. It wouldn't have been better as an answer, either, since the whole question is non-constructive.

Maybe my view is narrow, but if an answer is just a list of bullets, the question is *more-than-likely* non-constructive.  I'd venture that in your "ARM assembly manuals" example, the edit should be rejected, and if you have enough reputation, either vote to close or flag the question to close as non-constructive.

<sub>Disclaimer: Although it may look like it, I do not receive any financial compensation for using the word "non-constructive".  That would be cool, though.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the link is relevant and worth citing, yes, by all means, accept the edit. The only valid reasons to reject the edit would be

- as invalid (or custom) if the link is irrelevant or points to a bad resource;
- as too minor if you think the post should be deleted ASAP and no time should be wasted.

That doesn't change the fact that a bare list of links isn't a good Stack Exchange answer, so do navigate to the question page and after seeing this question vote to close.